# How to handling error loading csv files in python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, exception, error-handling

I am loading multiple csv files daily to a database table.
Source files are in Source folder
Once loading is completed, move to Archieve folder.
Code is working fine.
I am struggle to write exception error handling in this code.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

My Code in simple format:

```
Try:
Code to load
Except:
Logger.exception
Else:
Code to move file
```

My Original Code:

```
import logging
import logger
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd
import time
import numpy as np
import shutil
import os
source = "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\Scripts\\SourceFiles\\"
file_titles = ['C1','C2']
all_files = glob.glob(source + "/*Sales*.csv")
li = []
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=None,delimiter=',',names=file_titles,na_filter=False,skiprows=1,low_memory=False)
    li.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
Reporting_Date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
todaysdate = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")

df['CreatedDate'], df['CreatedBy'], df['LastModifiedDate'], df['LastModifiedBy'] = [todaysdate, 'User',todaysdate,'User']

try:
    import pyodbc
    sql_conn = pyodbc.connect(
        "Driver={SQL Server};"
        "Server=Server1;"
        "Database=DB;"
        "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
    cursor = sql_conn.cursor()
    for index,row in df1.iterrows():
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Table_Name ('C1','C2') Values (?,?)", 
                       row['C1'],
                       row['C2']
                      )
        sql_conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        sql_conn.close()
        print('Data Loading into table Table_Name is successful...')
except:  # something else went wrong
    #set different formats for logging output
    console_logging_format = '%(levelname)s:&amp;nbsp; %(message)s'
    file_logging_format = '%(levelname)s: %(asctime)s: %(message)s'
    # configure logger
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=console_logging_format)
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    # create a file handler for output file
    handler = logging.FileHandler('console_and_file.log')
    # set the logging level for log file
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    # create a logging format
    formatter = logging.Formatter(file_logging_format)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    # add the handlers to the logger
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    # output logging messages
    logger.info("save this to the log - info logger")
    logger.debug("save this to the log - debug logger")
    logger.error("save this to the log - error - logger")
    logger.warning("save this to the log - warning - logger")
    logger.critical("save this to the log - critical - logger")
else:
    dest1 = "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\Scripts\\Archieve\\"
    files = os.listdir(source)
    for f in files:
        shutil.move(source+f, dest1)
```